# Lenovo IdeaCentre 310S randomly restarting

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-desktop-computer

A colleague of mine recently recieved a new Lenovo IdeaCentre 310S. After some trouble we installed an SSD and installed a fresh version of windows 10 home (before all this the computer had the same problem)

But even after all that the computer still randomly just turns off without any notice or anything and starts back up like nothing happened. This happends randomly, so sometimes it restarts after a few hours of work. Sometimes even as little as 15 min after being turned on.

I have tried different settings, different powersaving settings etc. I have also googled around with 0 to no luck.

Anyone that also had/had this problem?

Kind regards,
Robbert

Answer (score 0):

If no blue screen is being displayed before it reboots, then it's almost certainly a hardware issue; contact Lenovo.

Comment: No blue screen, no popup, no warning at all. Could it be that because of the security update the PC is just struggling 24/7 and may be overloading constantly? The computer is a low end pc and struggles to run a few programs at once.